# WHERE IN clause in SqlServer with Millions of parameters - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

**Q: I need to pass Millions of parameters in WHERE IN clause, below is the scenario mentioned:**

I've two database servers SourceDB-server & DestinationDB-server, 
I need to Sync data from SourceDB TO DestinationDB, so I'm generating query dynamically through C# code, final query is mentioned below:

```
SelectQuery = "SELECT 
[tbltest01details].[testdetailsid],
[tbltest01details].[name],
[tbltest01details].[testid]  
FROM 
    [SourceServer].[SourceDB].[dbo]. [tbltest01details]  with (nolock)    
    WHERE 
    ( 
        [tbltest01details].[testid] 
        IN 
        (1,2,3.,.,.,......,80-million) 
    )";
```

WHERE IN Clause can be GUID OR Integer.

Above query will be executed on SourceServer through below method:

```
GetData(SourceConnectionString, SelectQuery, SourceTimeOut);
```

I've only Read-Access on SourceDB-Server, ie., I can only use SELECT query to get data from server.

**NOTE:** *Some may suggest using TEMPORARY table, but I cannot make TEMPORARY table on SourceDB-Server. Because I've only READ-Access on SourceDB-Server.*

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Millions of parameters?  Re-think your approach

Comment: 80mil? might as well `select * `  with no condition

Comment: I need to pass Millions of parameters in WHERE IN clause, what is best way to achieve it. Scenario is mentioned in my question.

Comment: From the oficial documents: `Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To work around this problem, store the items in the IN list in a table, and use a SELECT subquery within an IN clause.`

Comment: According to the documentation of CREATE TABLE *Any user can create temporary tables in tempdb.* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: where are your 80mil parameters coming from?

Comment: Why can't you use a sub-query or a regular join if they are on the same server?

Comment: Because when First Sync occurs that time that will work fine. ie., all records will be fetched. But when the next Sync will occur it will fetch All records once again.

Comment: @IrfanHabib why?, and why would writing every value in the `IN` solves this issue?

Comment: @Lamark: because I'm only concerned about NEW entries within the table after first Sync takes place. The IDs can reference on the same Table or other table.

Comment: 80-mil parameters are actually coming from, after getting Difference of ID's from SourceDB-Table & DestinationDB-Table, but I cannot use Sub-Query to get all ID's from that table. What I'm currently doing, I query to SourceDB server and get all those IDs in my DestinationDB server temp. table and then make the list of Comma separated parameters list for WHERE IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

But you can use a `SELECT` inside the `IN` clause

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE MYFK IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2)
```

Or... since you have to deal with MILLIONS of rows, can't you just select them all and then filter those needed by application code? If you need 80M rows in a 100M rows table that may be the easiest approach. if your table has 80 billions rows instead it might be not a good approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the `[tbltest01details].[testid]` is actually just a numerical value that you want your query to check against, you can use `BETWEEN`. If they are real distinct non-numerical parameters, there's literally no feasible way for you to do what you want to accomplish, and you need to re-think what you are actually doing.

i.e.

```
SelectQuery = "SELECT 
[tbltest01details].[testdetailsid],
[tbltest01details].[name],
[tbltest01details].[testid]  
FROM 
[SourceServer].[SourceDB].[dbo]. [tbltest01details]  with (nolock)    
WHERE 
( 
    [tbltest01details].[testid] 
    BETWEEN 1 AND 80000000
)";
```

Comment: If **[tbltest01details].[testid]**  is GUID then?

Comment: @IrfanHabib Then it's probably a good idea to put the right details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions to the question asked:

- Create a temporary table and fill it with values, any user can create temporary tables (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx#Permissions)
- Read Sommarskogs short article about arrays http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html and send chunks of values to SQL Server using a varchar(MAX) parameter.
- Use User Defined Table Valued Parameters, also very nice resource of Sommarskog http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#TVP
- Export the values to a CSV file and then import them into a staging table

In combination of any of these you would then perform a regular join with the data you wish to extract.